# Manage github Action Workflow with Prefect Cloud 2

Tags: python, deployment, github-actions, prefect

I have several GitHub action workflows to run. To manage them I want to use Prefect Cloud. I created a deployment and a GitHub block in Prefect. When I schedule a deployment to run, it stays in "late" state.

My repository structure:

```
my_git_repo
   └─github/workflows
       └─prefect_deployment.yml
       └─flow_run.yml
   flow_test.py
```

My Python flow code:

```
from prefect import flow, get_run_logger

@flow(name="Demo")
def basic_flow():
    logger=get_run_logger()
    logger.warning("Hello World")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    basic_flow()
```

My Prefect Block, linking to my repo:
[image]

This flow run is another workflow, flow_run.yml:

```
name: Run Flow
on: [workflow_dispatch]
jobs:
  run-flow:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set-Up-GitHub-Actions-Environment
        uses: actions/setup-python@v3
        with:
          python-version: 3.8
      - name: Install-Python-Packages
        run: |
          pip install prefect==2.8.3
      - name: flow-run
        run: |
          python3 flow_test.py
```

My YAML workflow code to create the deployment:

```
name: Deploy to Prefect Cloud 2

env:
  PREFECT_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.PREFECT_API_KEY }}
  PREFECT_API_URL: ${{ secrets.PREFECT_API_URL }}

on: [workflow_dispatch]

jobs:
  load-flow-to-prefect-cloud:
    name: Build and apply deployment
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 45
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          persist-credentials: false
          fetch-depth: 0
      
      - name: Set up Python 3
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: "3.8"
      - name: Install Python Packages
        run: |
          pip install prefect==2.8.3
      - name: Build deployment
        run: |
          prefect deployment build -n main_deployment flow_test.py:basic_flow \
             -sb github/test-block-github\
      
      - name : Apply deployment
        run: |
          prefect deployment apply basic_flow-deployment.yaml
```

The deployment created in Prefect Cloud:
[image]

When I try to run my flow it stays in the "late" Sate.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2):

Where is your agent running to retrieve and execute flow runs?
This looks like a workflow to register changes; with no infrastructure block specified, this is defaulting to 'process', but it's unclear where you expect this to run  -
`prefect deployment build -n main_deployment flow_test.py:basic_flow \ -sb github/test-block-github\`

Comment: I was probably unclear, I edit my question adding the name of my git infra-block.

Comment: Is there an agent running somewhere to kick off scheduled flow runs? https://docs.prefect.io/concepts/work-pools/#starting-an-agent

Comment: I don't have any agent running, shoud I add it in my Github workflow ? Because I want to trigger my Github Workflow from Prefect Cloud without having to run an agent locally.

Comment: You will need an agent running _somewhere_ that can execute the code , either locally, or in the cloud. A deployment sets up a "template" of _how_ to run a flow, and a flow run can be scheduled, but without anywhere to execute does nothing on its own. Simply starting a local agent with the default work-queue (because one was not passed) should pick up this flow run.

Comment: Just to trigger a workflow in need an agent running permanently on a server ? Are there any other orchestration tool not requiring  this ?